# MATLAB - faster writing to file

Tags: performance, file, matlab

I'm executing the following code to filter groups of four lines taken from one file, by the value of all characters in one of the lines (designated line q), and write the filtered lines to a new file.

```
fin = fopen(fname_in,'r') ;  
fout = fopen(fname_out,'w') ;  
y = 0 ;  
w = 0 ;  
fprintf(1,'Filtering') ;  
while ~feof (fin)  
  w=w+1 ;  
  if ~mod(w,50000) 
    fprintf(1,'.'); 
  end  
  t = fgets(fin) ;  
  s = fgets(fin) ;  
  p = fgets(fin) ;   
  q = fgets(fin) ;  
  if all(q(1:len) >= phred+phred_code)  
    y = y + 1 ;  
    fwrite(fout,[t s([1:len end]) p q([1:len end])]) ;  
  end  
end  

fclose(fin) ;  
fclose(fout) ;
```

The code is working, but it takes a very long time to run.

What other approach could accelerate the code?

thanks

Comment: What size are your files? Did you try profiling your code and see what part takes the longest? By the way, you can omit the `fileID` argument in `fprintf` if you want to write to the screen (`stdout` style).

Comment: Have you looked at the MATLAB `profile` command?  If you type `profile viewer` and click `Start Profiling`, then run your code, you can see which line is causing the problem.  Then it should be easier to get suggestions on ways to speed it up.

Comment: My files are very long - millions of lines per file. I'll try the profiling again.

Comment: Also, try to [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) the entire file: `textscan(fin, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n')`. If it's possible, maybe you can speed things up a little by working on the entire data set at once.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's faster to do fewer, but larger, reads and writes. If the file is small enough, you could read the entire file, process the lines, then write the entire file. If the file is too big for that, you can loop to read, process, and write chunks of the file instead of individual lines.

Comment: yes, while/for loops are very inefficient in matlab, it is best to avoid the work done in them. Avoid them entirely if possible, but this seems to be the only way to accomplish the task.

Comment: @KyleRogers I don't think looping is the culprit here. Doing one big read or write is simply faster than many small reads or writes. As for loops in general, they are usually pretty fast in modern Matlab because of the JIT accelerator.

Comment: The files are not small. I looked at the profiler again and most of the time is spent at fwrite, followed by some of the fgets (depending on line length). I don't see a way around it. Do you think taking the text files into pieces and then reassembling them can help?

Comment: @Yelin Processing in "chunks" is a good idea. I updated my answer.

Comment: I solved the problem by changing from Linux to Windows and somehow it runs much faster now (X5). Anyway, just to share - I didn't see any positive effect from **textscan**, it still took more or less the same time. I'm just guessing but I think my Linux is not installed properly and I'm taking care of it now. Thanks for your help.